# How to get a value from string after a specific substring?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My input string:

> Yth. ErzaPay.com (DS008206). Sal:465.670, Dlm proses:0. Pemakaian hr
>   ini:126.885 Komisi:0 #*IDN1,IDN3 Open harga naik

How can I get the string value `465.670` ?

Comment: is number is always preceded by  `sal:` or there's any sort of rule by which you're selecting `465.670` ?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a fairly strict format then you can use explode to get the value.
Other option it to use regex.

```
$temp = explode("Sal:",$str);
$sal = explode(",", $temp[1])[0];

echo $sal; //465.670
```

https://3v4l.org/Z6GfF

Answer (score 1):

```php
$string = "Yth. ErzaPay.com (DS008206). Sal:465.670, Dlm proses:0. Pemakaian hr ini:126.885 Komisi:0 #*IDN1,IDN3 Open harga naik";

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/(\w+):([\.\d]+)/', $string, $matches);
// var_dump($matches);

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/Sal:([\.\d]+)/', $string, $matches);
// var_dump($matches);
var_dump($matches[1][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `preg_match()` for this task.  It is cleanest to match the identifying substring, then reset the full string match with `\K`, then match 1 or more characters that are not a comma.  Job done.

Using `preg_match_all()` to extract a single string makes no logical sense.

I prefer not to make successive explosions because it is generating arrays on the way to isolating a substring.  In other words, it is simply indirect.  If you are going to use `explode()` to hack a string into smaller chunks while searching for a solitary substring, use the third parameter of `2` so that php doesn't carry on looking for more delimiters to explode on.

`strstr()` with a `true` third parameter extracts the portion of a substring before a first encountered substring, so this can be used instead of a second `explode()` call.

I could go on list other whacky techniques, but at the end of the day, regex affords a direct and concise solution, so I would likely use `preg_match()` in my production code.

You were not clear about how your input strings may vary.  I have only provided techniques suitable for your exact input.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a81VQ))

```
$input = 'Yth. ErzaPay.com (DS008206). Sal:465.670, Dlm proses:0. Pemakaian hr ini:126.885 Komisi:0 #*IDN1,IDN3 Open harga naik';

echo preg_match('~Sal:\K[^,]+~', $input, $out) ? $out[0] : 'no match';

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_replace('~^.*?Sal:|,.*?$~', '', $input);

echo "\n---\n";

echo strstr(explode('Sal:', $input, 2)[1], ',', true);

echo "\n---\n";

echo explode(',', explode('Sal:', $input, 2)[1], 2)[0];

echo "\n---\n";

if (($startPos = strpos($input, 'Sal:')) !== false && ($endPos = strpos($input, ',', $startPos)) !== false) {
    $substrPos = $startPos + 4;
    $substrLen = $endPos - $substrPos;
    echo substr($input, $substrPos, $substrLen);
}
```

Output:

```
465.670
---
465.670
---
465.670
---
465.670
---
465.670
```